# php string result to integer joomla plugin

Tags: php

I am stuck here, I am trying to access a value in my article.  I am working in soucerer, so I am able t use pure php code.

here is my code:

```
$tot_eval = '{plotalot id="32" P3="_P3" P1 = "_P1" P2 = "_P2" P4 = "_P4" P5 = "_P5"}'; 
echo $tot_eval;   // retunrs 366, I dont'see the brackets, but I know it is a string 
var_dump($tot_eval) = string('71)  "366"
```

I want this to be casted into a integer value, but if I do this

```
$tot_eval = (int)$tot_eval;    // return 0
$tot_eval = intval($tot_eval);  // returns 0
$tot_eval = $tot_eval +0 ;    //returns 0
```

I want to be able to add and use operators on multiple variable that will lok exactly like $tot_eval

```
$tot_eval = $tot_eval + $tot_eval ;    // returns 682
```

What his wrong?

Comment: What on earth is that first line?! It's certainly not an integer...

Comment: First line is a plugin that I use in joomla.  If I write this code in my editor, it will return the value 366.  If I print_r({plotalot....} );  I get the 366 value, I need that to be used as a value in my site to work on..

Comment: How does that line generate `366`? There's something very odd going on with `string('71)` in your debug. What's _actually_ output?

Comment: it's a joomla plugin called plotalot that does the work for me, let me check my debud

Comment: I have no clue how to see what is wrong in the debug?

Comment: after playing with it a lot, I figured out, var_dump($tot_eval) = "string(71) "215" " is the full string I receive.  I have not been able to get it to only return the 215, I tryed ob_clean(), as soon as I do something, I see the actual code, notthe value of i.  For example, if I do a substr($tot_eval,0,5) I ger this result:  "{plot" and not the actual value.  But if I only ech $tot_eval, I get 215 as the result, but I can't get it to be used for soemthing.